# ¿Cómo sumar valores de un arreglo que tiene un indice comùn?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
let arreglo = [['Enero 18', 100], ['Febrero 18', 200],['Enero 18', 400],  ['Febrero 18', 800], ['Marzo 19', 200], 'Marzo 19', 100]];
```

Si hay mes repetido, sumar el indice [1] de cada arreglo y como puedo obtener

```
let arregloReducido = [['Enero 18', 500], ['Febrero 18', 1000], ['Marzo 19', 300]];
```

Comment: Has intentado utilizar dos for anidados y hacer un nuevo arreglo a partir de comparaciones

Comment: Lo que estas sumando no es el índice 1, te aviso, corrije eso si no es precisamente ese índice con el que quieres trabajar

Comment: hola! Bienvenidx! Por favor, añade a tu pregunta el código con el que intentaste resolver este problema

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar **Array.prototype.reduce()** para hacer el trabajo más fácil. Con el ejemplo que muestras lo trabajarías así:

```js
let arreglo = [
    ["Enero 18", 100],
    ["Febrero 18", 200],
    ["Enero 18", 400],
    ["Febrero 18", 800],
    ["Marzo 19", 200],
    ["Marzo 19", 100]
];

// Creamos un objeto donde totalizamos los valores por arreglo[0]
const totalizado = arreglo.reduce((acum, actual) => {
    if (!acum[actual[0]]) {
        acum[actual[0]] = actual[1];
    } else {
        acum[actual[0]] = acum[actual[0]] + actual[1];
    }

    return acum;
}, {});

// Visualizar resultado
console.log(totalizado);
```

Más información:

- [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Me parece está debería ser la respuesta aceptada pues es simple y de calidad

Comment: es una buena forma de hacerlo... solo añadir que si lo que quieres es un arreglo en vez de un objeto solo debes cambiar en el final del reduce el `{}` por el `[]` y tendrás el mismo formato que en tu arreglo inicial

Answer (score 1):

A ver si te sirve esto, el arreglo original lo pasas por una función y despues empiezas a sumar y elminar los repetidos:

```
let arreglo = [["Enero 18", 100], ["Febrero 18", 200],["Enero 18", 400],  ["Febrero 18", 800], ["Marzo 19", 200], ["Marzo 19", 100]];
var arregloFinal=[]
recorrer(arreglo)
function recorrer(arreglo2){
  var yearsearch="";
  var total=0;
  var arreglo3=[];
  restartLoop:
  for(i=0; i<arreglo2.length; i++){
       if(yearsearch=="" || yearsearch==arreglo2[i][0]){
         yearsearch=arreglo2[i][0];
         total += arreglo2[i][1];
         arreglo2.splice(i, 1);
         i=-1;
       }
   }
  arreglo3.push(yearsearch)
  arreglo3.push(total)
  arregloFinal.push(arreglo3)
  if(arreglo2.length>0){
    recorrer(arreglo2);
  }else{
    console.log(arregloFinal)
  }

}
```

Consola del navegador:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DaZs.png